# Magento ver. 2.2.3 can't create order from backend

Tags: magento2, backend, create-order

From the backend when I try to place a new order and when I try to add new products, I'm getting following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function checkData() on null in /public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/AdminOrder/Create.php:1046
Stack trace:
#0 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/AdminOrder/Create.php(1063): Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create->addProduct(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\DataObject))
#1 public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Create.php(229): Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create->addProducts(Array)
#2 public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Create.php(134): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create->_processActionData()
#3 public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Create/LoadBlock.php(55): Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create->_processData()
#4 public_html/generated/code/Magento/Sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Cre in public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/AdminOrder/Create.php on line 1046
```

and in front, I'm getting following JS error.

```
POST https://test.test.com/admin/sales/order_create/loadBlock/key/9ef9328c45ba526d9cfffa10c9da9390cb3aa4e17a4b72c2c9fd1556b64432ec/block/search,items,shipping_method,totals,giftmessage,billing_method?isAjax=true 500 ()
```

I've made no changes to this process not even added in other modules for that.

Answer (score 0):

Please comment code $item->checkData() in that file and function so it will work . You need to override that file but for now you can edit directly as it is Magento 2 bug .